# Does Rails :delegate method always load the association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm using the :delegate method in Rails 3.2 to get/set methods on an object's association. This seems to **always** load the association, even when I'm not calling the delegated methods.

For instance, if I've got:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   delegate :name, :to => :author, :prefix => true
end
```

If I do `Post.all.limit(10)` ActiveRecord also loads the author for each of those posts, regardless of whether I'm ever accessing `@post.author_name`.

Is there a way to load delegated associations lazily? Or am I better off writing custom wrapper methods, which will load associations lazily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't eager-load for me, could it be something else in your code?

In any case I've never liked using `delegate` with `prefix`, it seems kind of odd. You're no longer actually delegating a method, you've just defined a new method in a difficult to read and parse way. I'd just write a wrapper method as you suggested.

Comment: It could be something in my code, but I've not been able to see where. I don't actually use `prefix` either, but added it here for the clarity of my example. For other reasons, I've moved to using wrapper methods anyway (`delegate` is kind of awkward for saving records, in my opinion).